# Converting a datatable search to a lambda expression

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, lambda, ado.net

I need help converting this for loop to a LINQ/Lambda expression in VB.NET:

```
For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
    Dim firstName As String = CStr(dr("FirstName")).ToLower()
    Dim lastName As String = CStr(dr("LastName")).ToLower()

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) Then
        If firstName.ToLower = "john" AndAlso lastName.ToLower = "doe" Then
            Return "Found"
        End If
    End If
Next

Return "Not Found"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: This might help get you in the right direction:http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/193518/using-of-lambda-expression-and-removing-foreach-fo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim row = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of String)("FirstName").ToLower = "john" AndAlso f.Field(Of String)("LastName").ToLower = "doe").FirstOrDefault()

    Return If(row Is Nothing, "Not Found", "Found")
```